# QT QMessageBox control linebreak

Tags: qt, line-breaks, qmessagebox

I use QT QMessageBox to show an error message.
The problem is, when the error message is something like

```
    Error opening file at location 'C:\Users\User\some_folder\some_file'
```

qt inserts linebreak after the ':' in the path, instead of using one of the withespaces:

```
    Error opening file at location 'C:
    \Users\User\some_folder\some_file'
```

Is there a way to tell not to break line after char ':'?
I would likely have

```
    Error opening file at location 
    'C:\Users\User\some_folder\some_file'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work, as I have not tested it, but you can use HTML subset which is suppoertd by Qt. This subset contains `<nobr>` element. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html

So try this `QString msg = "Error opening file at location <nobr>'C:\Users\User\some_folder\some_file'</nobr>";` and then send this string to the `QMessageBox`.

Comment: Thank you. This should be the correct answer, still, I can get it to work. It looks like the `<nobr>` is not fully supported by qt, and you can expect it to work whit whitespaces but not with characters as **:** or **-**, see the many related bug reports e.g. [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-1135) or [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-12057)